# How do I check if two instances of a Django model are the same across a set of attributes and annotate a queryset accordingly?

Tags: python, sql, django

My app has a model "OptimizationResult", where I store results from mathmatical optimization. The optimization distributes timeslots over projects. I need to indicate whether the current results is different from a recent result, based on a set of attributes (in particularly not the primary key)

The attribute optimization_run is a coutner for different runs
Project is a ForeignKey to the project.

By overwriting the `__hash__` and `__eq__` functions on the model I can compare  the different instances by

```py
OptimizationResults.objects.filter(proj = 1).filter(optimization_run =1).first() == OptimizationResults.objects.filter(proj = 1).filter(optimization_run = 2).first()
```

. But as I understand `__eq__` and `__hash__` are not available on the database.

How would I annotate the results accordingly? Something like

```py
OptimizationResults.objects.filter(optimization_run = 2).annotate(same_as_before = Case(When(),default=False))
```

**Edit**
Added .first() to the code, to ensure that there is only one element.

```
class OptimizationResult(models.Model):
    project = models.ForeignKey(project, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    request_weight = models.IntegerField()
    periods_to_plan = models.IntegerField()
    unscheduled_periods = models.IntegerField()
    scheduled_periods = models.IntegerField()
    start = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True, default=None)
    end = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True, default=None)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('Erstellungsdatum', auto_now_add=True, editable=False)
    optimization_run= models.ForeignKey(OptimizationRun, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

I'd like to compore different entries on the basis of *start* and *end*.

**Edit 2**

My fruitless attempt with Subquery:

```py
old = OptimizationResult.objects.filter(project=OuterRef('pk')).filter(optimization_run=19)
newest = OptimizationResult.objects.filter(project=OuterRef('pk')).filter(optimization_run=21)
Project.objects.annotate(changed = Subquery(newest.values('start')[:1])== Subquery(old.values('start')[:1]))
```

results in  TypeError: QuerySet.annotate() received non-expression(s): False

Comment: Your `OptimizationResults.objects.filter(..)` is a list, right? How do you guarantee that the order of the two lists is the same?

Comment: Is it possible to share (relevant parts of) your `OptimizationResults` model?

Comment: There is only one result. (I'll add first() it in the code above) and add the model

Comment: So you want to check if all the fields, except the `optimization_run` and `pk` are the same, right?

Comment: yes, and put that in annotation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use a subquery here, to make an annotation:

```
from django.db.models import Exists, OuterRef, Subquery, Q

to_exclude = {'pk', 'id', 'project', 'project_id', 'optimization_run', 'optimization_run_id'}

subquery = OptimizationResult.objects.filter(
    project_id=OuterRef('project_id')
    optimization_run=1,
    **{f.name: OuterRef(f.name)
        for f in OptimizationResult._meta.get_fields()
        if f.name not in to_exclude
    }
)

OptimizationResult.objects.filter(
    optimization_run=2
).annotate(
    are_same=Exist(subquery)
)
```

Here we will thus annotate all the `OptimizationResult`s with an `optimization_run=2`, with an extra attribute `.are_same` that checks if there exists an `OptimizationResult` object for `optimization_run=1` and for the *same* `project_id`, where all fields are the same, except the ones in the `to_exclude` set.

Comment: Thanks, it works like a charm. Appenrently, I forgot a part of the question: Can I now add that somehow in a conditional expression of Case(When())?

Comment: @Jochen: you could add an extra annotation, and use `are_same` as if it was a field defined on that object.

Comment: @Jochen: but the `Exists` is more or less a conditonal expression, it will return a `True`/`False`. You can for example add extra filtering, etc. to count the number of `OptimizationResult`s that are different.